# Why is the "axiom of extension" an axiom?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axioms

I think this is a definition of = because it explains the meaning of the **new symbol** =. However, I wonder why the set theory thinks this as an axiom rather than a definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality).

There are two possibilities :

*(i)* the underlying logic is predicate calculus **with** *equality*.

In this case, the symbol $=$ is already defined by the [equality axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) and *Extensionality* is needed only to legislate the "interaction" with $\in$ :

> $∀x∀y∀z [(z ∈ x \leftrightarrow z ∈ y) \to x = y]$.

*(ii)* the  underlying logic is predicate calculus **without** *equality*.

In this case you are right : we need a specific definition for *equality* :

> $a=b =_{def} \forall x [x \in a \leftrightarrow x \in b]$

and a different version of *Extensionality* :

> $\forall z \forall x \forall y [x = y \to (x \in z \to y \in z)]$.

From them we can derive the usual properties of equality.

Comment: +1 Very enlightening.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you tell me exactly what the (slightly different) version of Extensionality is?

Comment: I just read your edited answer. Thank you so much!